# how to include class library reference into docker file

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

i'm trying to build docker file for .net core application which is having reference of class library whenever i'm trying to build docker i'm getting below error.

**Skipping project because it was not found**

below is the docker file which i'm using

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testapp.dll"]
```

Comment: where's your dockerfile located relative to your csproj file? and in what path are you running docker build? this does not seem to be a class library reference issue, but your csproj is not found.

Comment: @MarkusDresch my dockerfile is located into root folder and also im running build command on same root folder

Answer (score 7):

You need to move the Dockerfile to the solution level, and reference the projects using [Folder]/[Project].csproj.
Here is my Dockerfile (located in the solution level):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SumApi/SumApi.csproj", "SumApi/"]
COPY ["Shared/Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SumApi/SumApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SumApi"
RUN dotnet build "SumApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SumApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app`enter code here`
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SumApi.dll"]
```

Learned it from here: https://imranarshad.com/dockerize-net-core-web-app-with-dependent-class-library/

Answer (score 3):

### Answer using .NET 8 and [chiseled containers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-chiseled-containers/) that create smaller, more secure container images

Full source code [here](https://github.com/akhanalcs/docker-with-classlib).

---

For creating a docker image of an app (`MyCoolTestApp.API`) with a dependent library(`MyCoolTestApp.Lib`) as shown below:

```bash
docker-with-classlib
├── MyCoolTestApp.API
│   ├── MyCoolTestApp.API.csproj
│   └── other files...
├── MyCoolTestApp.Lib
│   ├── MyCoolTestApp.Lib.csproj
│   └── other files...
├── MyCoolTestApp.sln
├── MyCoolTestApp.API.Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
└── .dockerignore
```

You can create docker image with this dockerfile:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-jammy AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj files and restore as distinct layers
COPY "MyCoolTestApp.API/*.csproj" "MyCoolTestApp.API/"
COPY "MyCoolTestApp.Lib/*.csproj" "MyCoolTestApp.Lib/"
RUN dotnet restore "MyCoolTestApp.API/MyCoolTestApp.API.csproj"

# copy and build app and libraries
COPY "MyCoolTestApp.API/" "MyCoolTestApp.API/"
COPY "MyCoolTestApp.Lib/" "MyCoolTestApp.Lib/"
WORKDIR "/source/MyCoolTestApp.API"
RUN dotnet publish -o /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:8.0-jammy-chiseled-composite
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyCoolTestApp.API"]
```

Build the image like this by navigating to `docker-with-classlib` folder:

```bash
docker build -f MyCoolTestApp.API.Dockerfile . -t ashk/my-cool-api:0.1.0
```

Run the container like this:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8080 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development ashk/my-cool-api:0.1.0
```