# Dockerfile fails because I cannot copy the class library it depends on

Tags: c#, .net, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to build an image from a Dockerfile. The problem is that it is not able to find the Messages Class Library which means I have to do something like `COPY ["src/MarketData.Subscriber/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj", "MarketData.Subscriber/"] COPY ["src/MarketData.Messages/MarketData.Messages.csproj", "MarketData.Messages/"]` but COPY fails when I add these below WORKDIR. How do I solve it?

### Folder Structure

```
 .
 +---src
 |   +---MarketData.Api
 |   +---MarketData.Messages
 |   +---MarketData.Subscriber
 |       +---Dockerfile
 +---MarketData.sln
```

### Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1 - Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /app/src

# Restore
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore -r linux-x64

# Build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore

# Stage 2 - Publish
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 101 app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app --uid 101 app


COPY --from=builder --chown=app:app /app/publish .

USER app
ENTRYPOINT ["./MarketData.Subscriber"]
```

### Error

```
[+] Building 4.0s (14/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 589B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0                                                                                                                                           0.4s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [builder 1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0@sha256:66a16cd71b82a2df577e52dfd01d8039ed4c20e3f17fca31b2fb3cf5929eaa7f                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 650B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/4] RUN addgroup --system --gid 101 app     && adduser --system --ingroup app --uid 101 app                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/6] WORKDIR /app/src                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/6] COPY *.csproj .                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/6] RUN dotnet restore -r linux-x64                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore                                                                                         3.5s
------
 > [builder 6/6] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore:
#14 0.567 MSBuild version 17.4.0-preview-22368-02+c8492483a for .NET
#14 1.270 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100-preview.7.22377.5/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(219,5): message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-support-policy [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 1.532 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100-preview.7.22377.5/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2082,5): warning : The referenced project '../MarketData.Messages/MarketData.Messages.csproj' does not exist. [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(3,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Messages' does not exist in the namespace 'MarketData' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(1,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Messages' does not exist in the namespace 'MarketData' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.416 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemConfiguration.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemHostedService.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemHostedService.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Proto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(10,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FtxSubscriptionBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(12,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClusterIdentity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(18,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(19,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClusterIdentity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemHostedService.cs(8,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActorSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/ActorSystemHostedService.cs(11,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActorSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(36,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SubscriptionRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(51,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SubscriptionRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
#14 3.417 /app/src/Actors/FtxSubscriptionGrain.cs(57,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SubscriptionStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/src/MarketData.Subscriber.csproj]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Check out this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592431/8644294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cisien, the issue was fixed. It was due to how I was running the build.

It should be run from the root and `docker build . -f src/Dockerfile`. The '.' denotes the build context, or in other words, the parent directory that is made available to the docker build process.

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\MarketData>docker build -t marketdata:1.0 -f ./src/MarketData.Subscriber/Dockerfile .

Hope it helps someone else.

### Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1 - Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /app/src

# Restore
COPY src/MarketData.Messages/MarketData.Messages.csproj MarketData.Messages/
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish --no-self-contained --no-restore

# Stage 2 - Publish
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 101 app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app --uid 101 app

COPY --from=builder --chown=app:app /app/publish .

USER app
ENTRYPOINT ["./MarketData.Subscriber"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your dockerfile at solution level. then only it will be able to find src folder.

your folder structure should look like this.

```
.
 +---src
 |   +---MarketData.Api
 |   +---MarketData.Messages
 |   +---MarketData.Subscriber
 +---MarketData.sln
 +---Dockerfile
```

and also add respective copy project fie cmd to dockerfile.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've seen several microservices projects including the one from Microsoft https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers and they do have their Dockerfiles in the src/ProjectName folder. How did they achieve that?

Comment: I guess they are using docker-compose to build the image and in that case the build context is set at higher level. you can also try the same. if your goal is to use docker-compose in the end.

Comment: ` => ERROR [builder 4/6] RUN dotnet restore -r linux-x64                                                                                                                                                     0.7s
------
 > [builder 4/6] RUN dotnet restore -r linux-x64:
#12 0.622 MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -r linux-x64]: exit code: 1`

Comment: I assume I need to bulid the solution when I move the Dockerfile to be near the .sln?

Comment: you need to specify the main project in the restore step , it will internally restore all other dependent projects.

Comment: Could you please show the edit in the Dockerfile?

Comment: which one is your main project out of these three ?

Comment: MarketData.Api and MarketData.Subscriber are both main projects i.e. Web API projects that I need Dockerfiles for. They both depend on MarketData.Messages. The Api one provides some endpoints to the end user and the subscriber will be clustered (spawn more nodes for it).

Comment: then you simple need to provide the path of subscriber project like `MarketData.Messages/MarketData.Messages.csproj` in restore step.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't work when I put the Dockerfile inside MarketData.Subscriber project folder because I'm trying to create the docker image through the cmd `docker build -t marketdata:1.0 .` and not through docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, you can move the docker file to one back folder.
For example, folder1/folder2/dockerfile move to folder1/dockerfile and build the image.

```
Docker build -t imagename .

Docker run -p 7778:80 imagename
```

It works for me.